# how to insert new row into a specific section by tapping on cell of that section : I want layout like iPhone edit contact screen swift uitablview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, insert, cell

Blockquote

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70b6R.jpg)
this is what I have achieved so far in this regard and my ultimate goal is to design screen like image shared below. one thing I would like to mention is that it works well when I click on mobile cell and it inserts  a new row custom row above it but whenever I add code for below too fields it throws an exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY6tI.jpg)
just have a look at picture this is what I want to achieve whenever I click on add email cell i could insert new row into that section and when I click on add phone I can insert new row above that cell which is of phone type

```
         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                _ = indexPath.row
                // print(indexPath)
                //myTableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
               myTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
                if(indexPath.section == 1) {
                   // print(indexPath)
                    print("hello")
                    myTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                    _ = setEditing(true, animated: true)
                   // myTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
                   //phone.insert("Company", at: indexPath.row)
                     //   myTableView.beginUpdates()
                        //  _ = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: //"ContactMenuTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactMenuTableViewCell
                                  
                              //  myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
                              //myTableView.endUpdates()
                    }
               else if(indexPath.section == 2){
                    print("oye hoye")
                    myTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                    print("maan bhi jao")
                _ = setEditing(true, animated: true)
              
                }
               else if(indexPath.section == 3){
               
                  myTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                  _ = setEditing(true, animated: true)
                     // myTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
                  //  if selectedIndexPath == indexPath.row {
                   /* address.insert(" new country", at: indexPath.row)
                         myTableView.beginUpdates()
                        //  let datePickerCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PhoneTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! PhoneTableViewCell
                     myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)], with: .automatic)
                         myTableView.endUpdates()
                     */
                    }
        
              //set editing function  used to perform editing on cells
            }override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
            if editing{
                    print("12345")
                if isEditing{
                    self.myTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                      myTableView.beginUpdates()
                      myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: phone.count ,section: 1)], with: .automatic)
                    myTableView.endUpdates()}
                print("missing u ")
            } else if editing  {
                    print("heloo guys how u  doing g")
                    self.myTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                      myTableView.beginUpdates()
                      myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: email.count ,section: 2)], with: .automatic)
                              myTableView.endUpdates()
                } else if editing {
                    print("hurra g")
                   // self.myTableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                      myTableView.beginUpdates()
                      myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: address.count ,section: 3)], with: .automatic)
                              myTableView.endUpdates()
                }
                    
                else{
                    self.myTableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                    myTableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row:phone.count, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
                    self.myTableView.endUpdates()
                }
            } 
        // editing style function
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
               
               if editingStyle == .delete{
                   self.fields.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                   self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
                       myTableView.deleteRows(at :[IndexPath(row : 0 , section: 0)], with: .fade)
                       self.myTableView.endUpdates()
                   
               }else if editingStyle == .insert {
                    if indexPath.section == 1{
                        print("i am new")
                    self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.phone.insert("company", at: 1)
                        myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
                        self.myTableView.endUpdates()
                    } else if indexPath.section == 2{
                        print("dekho")
                        self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
                        self.email.insert("home", at: 0)
                        myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2)], with: .automatic)
                        self.myTableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                    else if indexPath.section == 3{
                        self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
                        self.address.insert("home", at: 0)
                        myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)], with: .automatic)
                        self.myTableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
        
               
                } 
        // different section with custom cells
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                switch indexPath.section{
                case 0:
                    let TextCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextTableViewCell
                                     TextCell.placeHolder.placeholder = fields[indexPath.row]
                                     TextCell.selectionStyle = .none
                                         return TextCell
                case 1:
                    if  indexPath.row == self.phone.count && self.isEditing == true{
                                  print(indexPath.row)
                                let hellocell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactMenuTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactMenuTableViewCell
                               hellocell.newcontact.text = "Insert a new cell"
                                  return hellocell
                               }
                     let phoneCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhoneTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhoneTableViewCell
                               // phoneCell.configure(with: "Add Phone", imageName: "gear")
                 phoneCell.addPhone.text = phone[indexPath.row]
                                return phoneCell
               case 2:
                if  indexPath.row == self.email.count && self.isEditing == true{
                   print(indexPath.row)
                 let insertCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextTableViewCell
                 //insertCell.emailInsert.placeholder = fields[indexPath.row]
                                             insertCell.selectionStyle = .none
                                                 return insertCell
                }
               if  indexPath.row == self.email.count && self.isEditing == true{
                           print(indexPath.row)
                         let hellocell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactMenuTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactMenuTableViewCell
                        hellocell.newcontact.text = "Insert a new cell"
                           return hellocell
                        }
                    let emailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmailTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EmailTableViewCell
                emailCell.emaillabel.text = email[indexPath.row]
                    return emailCell
                case 3:
                    
                   let addressCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddressTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
                   addressCell.addressLabel.text = address[indexPath.row]
                   return addressCell
                default:
                    return UITableViewCell()
                }
            
           // number of rows function
         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if section == 1{
                if self.isEditing{
                     return phone.count + 1
                }else{
                    return phone.count
                }
            }  else if section == 2{
                if self.isEditing{
                     return email.count + 1
                }else{
                    return email.count
                }
            } else if section == 3{
                return address.count
            }else{
               return  fields.count
            }
        
            }
    
    // how to insert new row into specific section of tableview by tapping on existing cell of that section
    // also how to disable set editing function on other section while inserting row 
    // how to achieve insert cell functionality
    // i am designing a layout of edit contact like your iOS contact screen 
    // if anybody have code please help me out
// any help would be appreciated
//tableview cells
//inserting new rows 
// swipe to delete row
//swift
// uitableview
```

//A UITableViewCell object is a specialized type of view that manages the content of a single table row. You use cells primarily to organize and present your app’s custom content, but UITableViewCell provides some specific customizations to support table-related behaviors, including:
Applying a selection or highlight color to the cell.
Adding standard accessory views, such as a detail or disclosure control.
Putting the cell into an editable state.
Indenting the cell's content to create a visual hierarchy in your table.
Your app’s content occupies most of the cell’s bounds, but the cell may adjust that space to make room for other content. Cells display accessory views on the trailing edge of their content area. When you put your table into edit mode, the cell adds a delete control to the leading edge of its content area, and optionally swaps out an accessory view for a reorder control.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the description you gave. Please be specific about your question.

Comment: When you want to add a cell you add data to your model (fields ?) and then call reloadData or insertRow on tableView object.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am designing a layout similar to iPhone built in edit contact screen so I want to achieve those features mean I want to say that whenever I click on add phone I could insert a new row above that cell in that  particular section